# What is in this squiggly brackets?

Tags: python

it is a Python str.format() question

Please see below-
I cannot seem to understand the purpose of 2d in the {:2d} part...
I see that : keeps the print output on the same output line...
When I change the 2d to 2e it changes the printed result somehow, but i'm not sure what this code inside formatters is or is doing

```
   print("a =", a, ":", end=" ")
   for b in range(1, 11):
     print("{:2d}".format(a*b), end=" ")
   print()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Most of the basic questions like this have answers already, so it is always better to search before asking ^^. But those parenthesis , when used inside strings, are for formatting the string. You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/).

Comment: It specifies the [type format](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/).

Answer (score -1):

2 is number of space to be left for formating and d means only integer can come

eg

```
 2
 4
44
444
```